# valid publishable key set, yet get no valid publishable key set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I am trying to make stripe checkout sample from stripe website works

https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/rails

, yet when I try to pay, I receive this **error message**.

> You did not set a valid publishable key. Call
>   Stripe.setPublishableKey() with your publishable key. For more info,
>   see https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js

In my **JavaScript** console the **error message** is

> https://checkout.stripe.com/api/bootstrap?key=&locale=en-US Failed to
>   load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

In my **console** the **error message** is

> Started GET "/" for 10.240.1.15 at 2016-10-19 17:29:24 +0000 Cannot
>   render console from 10.240.1.15! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1,
>   127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255 Processing by ChargesController#new as HTML   Rendered charges/new.html.erb within layouts/application (0.5ms)
>   Completed 200 OK in 53ms (Views: 52.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

**When I check my html source code stripe-key meta tag does not have any content?**

The stripe sample uses their own secret and publishable keys, yet I use mine.

**Please, if more info is needed, ask, so I can post.**

**application.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Workspace</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag  'https://js.stripe.com/v2/' %> 
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <%= tag :meta, :name=> 'stripe-key', :content => ENV["STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY"] %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

**charges.html.erb**

```
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

**stripe.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    Stripe.setPublishableKey($('meta[name="stripe-key"]').attr('content'));        
});
```

**stripe.rb**

```
Rails.configuration.stripe = {
  :publishable_key => ENV['PUBLISHABLE_KEY'],
  :secret_key      => ENV['SECRET_KEY']
}

Stripe.api_key = Rails.configuration.stripe[:secret_key]
```

Comment: Are you hosting Stripe.js from your own server?

Comment: @Korben I show my stripe.js content. I don't know more than that

Comment: In stripe.rb you're setting your publishable key as `ENV['PUBLISHABLE_KEY']` but in your meta tag it is `ENV["STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY"]` - what happens if you use `<%= tag :meta, :name=> 'stripe-key', :content => ENV["PUBLISHABLE_KEY"] %>`?

Comment: @MikeH I tried, yet the same error

Comment: Do you get the same error if you put the publishable key directly as an argument in `Stripe.setPublishableKey` (instead of getting the value from the meta tag)?

Comment: Yes I do get the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually added the publishable key in the new.html.erb like that:

```
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
      Stripe.setPublishableKey('PUBLISHABLE_KEY');
      data-key="<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>"
      data-description="A month's subscription"
      data-amount="100"
      data-locale="auto">
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same problem,
to solve it , just put this code into your stripe.rb file

config/initializers/stripe.rb

```
Rails.configuration.stripe = {
  publishable_key: Rails.application.secrets.stripe_publishable_key,
  secret_key: Rails.application.secrets.stripe_secret_key
}
Stripe.api_key = Rails.configuration.stripe[:secret_key]
```

of course after you put the test_keys into `config/secrets.yml`

Answer (score 0):

In `stripe.rb`, you're setting `:publishable_key` from `ENV['PUBLISHABLE_KEY']`, while in `application.html.erb` you use `ENV["STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY"]`. You should probably update `application.html.erb` to use `Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key]` instead:

```
  <%= tag :meta, :name=> 'stripe-key', :content => Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>
```

That said, the issue is likely that you did not set the [environment variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable). Can you try setting the keys directly in `stripe.rb` instead? E.g.:

```
Rails.configuration.stripe = {
  :publishable_key => 'pk_...',
  :secret_key      => 'sk_...'
}
```

As a reminder, you can find you API keys in your Stripe dashboard: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys.